# Does the function $\sqrt[4]{4−4}$ have an inverse?

Tags: inverse-function

The function: $\sqrt[4]{4−4}$, $x≤1$ is supposed to have an inverse function of:
$(−^4/4)+1$.

But the puzzle is that the function $(−^4/4)+1$ fails the horizontal line test so how on earth could it be the inverse function of $\sqrt[4]{4−4}$.

Is there some sort of explanation for that? Or that the doesn't have an inverse?

```
              Green = function: ∜(4−4) 
              Red = function:  (−^4/4)+1
```

Here's the graph:
[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UlD1.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: (4-4x)^1/4 has its range from (0,inf), therefore the domain of its inverse is defined from (0,inf) so you don't consider the part where x<0 for the inverse function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function
$$
\begin{array}{cccc}
  f:&(-\infty,1]&\longrightarrow&\mathbb{R}\\
  &x&\mapsto&\sqrt[4]{4-4x}
\end{array}
$$
is injective (since it is strictly increasing) and its range is $[0,+\infty)$. Therefore, it has an inverse $g:[0,+\infty)\longrightarrow(-\infty,1]$. In order to get an analytic expression for $g$, observe that
\begin{align}
f(x)=y&\iff\sqrt[4]{4-4x}=y\\
&\iff 4-4x=y^4\\
&\iff x=1-\frac{y^4}4.
\end{align}
So, $\displaystyle g(x)=1-\frac{x^4}4$. The graph of $g$ is the right half of your red graph, which doesn't fail the horizontal line test.

Comment: What I understood is that with inverse functions I only care about the part that reflects my original function especially when changing the y-x's and solving for y gives me a resulting function. That was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Just take care of the domains and  make the codomains equal to the ranges.

$f: (-\infty,1] \to [0,\infty)$ with $f(x)= \sqrt[4]{4-4x}$

has the inverse

$g:  [0,\infty) \to (-\infty,1]$ with $g(y)= 1-\frac{x^4}{4}$